# XMLEventWriter from scratch: how do I emit xmlns attribute?

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces, stax

I am trying to write an XML document from scratch using the XMLEventWriter from the StAX API.

I cannot figure out how to get the default namespace attribute to be emitted.

For example, the default namespace URI string is "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9".  I want that to be present in my XML root element as xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9".

What's the magic recipe here?  XMLEventWriter.setDefaultNamespace() didn't work.

Thanks,
Laird

Comment: I should mention that I can get it emitted if I add it as an explicit Namespace, and construct an Iterator that includes that Namespace, and call the most-parameterized version of XMLEventFactory#createStartElement().  But I would have thought XMLWriter.setDefaultNamespace() would have done *something*.  I don't see that it has any effect at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the property [IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.html#IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES) to set this behaviour:

```
XMLEventFactory events = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
QName bar = new QName("urn:bar", "bar");
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);
XMLEventWriter writer = factory.createXMLEventWriter(System.out);
writer.add(events.createStartDocument());
writer.setDefaultNamespace("urn:bar");
writer.add(events.createStartElement(bar, null, null));
writer.add(events.createEndDocument());
writer.flush();
```

The above code emits:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><bar xmlns="urn:bar"></bar>
```

Comment: What if I'm reading an element in from an XMLEventReader and then writing it with the XMLEventWriter, and need to add the namespace to a certain element, not creating an event with createStartElement? How can I add a namespace then?

Answer (score -1):

Use "write*" instead of "set*"

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter.writeDefaultNamespace(String)
```

Comment: Hi, Martin; thanks, but the question was about XMLEventWriter, not XMLStreamWriter.